# Inverse re.split

Tags: python

I have this `C:/Users/nash08/Desktop/NUKE_OITO_MEDIA/PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx`

I want to remove everything thats in the path till the words produtoras like this:

```
/PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx
```

My knowledge in regular expressions its pretty mediocre, the only way that I am used to is to separate the path by `/` like this

```
rpath = path.rsplit('/',1)[0]
rpath2 = re.split('/',path)
```

and index to where I want.

Answer (score 3):

You're using regular expression.
That works:

```
t = "C:/Users/nash08/Desktop/NUKE_OITO_MEDIA/PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx"
output = re.search(".*(/PRODUTORAS.*)", t)
print output.group(1)
>'/PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx'
```

Comment: Perhaps make the first dot nongreedy (`.*?`) in case that there are more than one component of the path with PRODUTORAS in the name.

Comment: Nice idea, that would depend on the application though. The user could want the greedy alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach:

```
if '/PRODUTORAS/' in mypath:
    newpath = '/PRODUTORAS/' + mypath.split('/PRODUTORAS/', 1)[1]
```

This only works if you are using forward slashes for your path separator and `PRODUTORAS` is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

If your prefix doesn't change, this code will work:

```
path = "C:/Users/nash08/Desktop/NUKE_OITO_MEDIA/PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx"
prefix = "C:/Users/nash08/Desktop/NUKE_OITO_MEDIA/"

print path.strip(prefix)

#Output:
>>> 'PRODUTORAS/PYTHON/WORK_INTERNO/_CENAS_FX/N10/N01_V01_NK08.%04d.dpx'
```